# Initializing an array of doubles java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, initialization, double

I cannot for the life of me understand why this code isn't working. I am creating a function to evaluate a polynomial at all of the points over a given x interval, at a frequency specified by the user. My underlying Polynomial code is irrelevent to the problem. My problem is filling my array with the values I am obtaining from Horner's method.

```
public double[] evalAt(double s, double f, int n) {
    double[] resultArray = new double[n];
    double h =((f - s)/(n));
    if(s==f) {
        double tempResult = 0;
        for (int i = this.degree; i >= 0; i--) {
            tempResult = tempResult * s + this.terms[i].getCoefficient();
        }
        resultArray[0] = tempResult;
    } else {
        int counter = 0;
        for(double i = s; i <= f; i=i+h) {
            double tempResult = 0;
            for (int j = this.degree; j >= 0; j--) {
                tempResult = tempResult * i + this.terms[j].getCoefficient();
            }
            System.out.println("Counter: " + counter + " Result @ Counter: " + tempResult);
            resultArray[counter++] = tempResult;
        }
        System.out.println(resultArray[0]);
        System.out.println(resultArray[1]);
        System.out.println(resultArray[2]);
        System.out.println(resultArray[3]);
    }
    return resultArray;
}
```

I have a `print` statement in there to show me what the values of the counter and the temporary result are. then I use the `resultArray['index'] = 'value';` syntax. When I run this, I see that the counter and the value are exactly as I want them, however when I check the array with the four `print` statements at the bottom, nothing happens. My inputs are `0,10,10`:

Output:

```
Counter: 0 Result @ Counter: 0.0
Counter: 1 Result @ Counter: 1.0
Counter: 2 Result @ Counter: 4.0
Counter: 3 Result @ Counter: 9.0
Counter: 4 Result @ Counter: 16.0
Counter: 5 Result @ Counter: 25.0
Counter: 6 Result @ Counter: 36.0
Counter: 7 Result @ Counter: 49.0
Counter: 8 Result @ Counter: 64.0
Counter: 9 Result @ Counter: 81.0
Counter: 10 Result @ Counter: 100.0
```

Comment: Why don't you fix your indentation and look again?  My guess is that the brackets aren't doing what you think they are.

Comment: neither solution has worked, although I do appreciate the prompt answer.

Comment: So what is the output from those last 4 print statements? You say "nothing happens", but what do you mean by that? Is it not executing those statements? Is it throwing an exception that gets swallowed somewhere? Have you tried stepping through with a debugger to see exactly which lines are executed?

Comment: Does your code terminate after the output you provided, or does it continue to run? (i.e. is it hanging somewhere?)

Comment: I think you'll get the best help if you post code that people can actually run for themselves, state what it is you're getting and also what is the expected output. Try to cut your code down to the smallest possible example that has the bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly suspect it is throwing an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException which is getting swallowed outside this method.

You are creating an array of size `n`, in this case 10, but your counter goes from zero to `f` (also 10) which is a total of 11 elements. So there's an off-by-one in at least one of those.

Look through your code and find the bit that says

```
catch (Exception e) {
}
```

and change it to

```
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

to help catch this kind of error more easily.

Comment: I was handling exceptions elsewhere in the program and it was in fact an array out of bounds exception... thanks so much to everyone!

Comment: Do the mental check where n=1  You want two results, at the beginning and the end.  resultArray[] must be dimensioned to 2, not 1.  So your 2nd line must be [n+1].

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I can't post comments yet as this isn't a concrete answer but I have checked and run your code and it runs fine for me.  Substituting in a fixed coefficient and degree show that the bracketing is all fine and that you aren't (as I suspected) reinitialising the resultArray variable in an inner scope.

Is this a direct copy/paste of the problematic code that you have?

Typically when I have an issue like this it is nothing to do with the assignment but instead it is because 'resultsArray' is actually 2 different variables that I have erroneously allocated but which I am receiving no errors for because of polymorphism.

Comment: yep this is a direct copy and paste. When I sub in '0' instead of counter++ I get the last tempResult (as it was overwritten until the loop end) in the '0'th element and then all of the other elements will show me a 0.0 as their contents. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: You're welcome :)  In your post where you say "nothing happens" when you print out the resultArray contents what exactly are you seeing?  Do you mean nothing is printed our whatsoever or the values are wrong?

Comment: If you are getting no output whatsoever then I would say you should wrap the whole method contents in a try{} catch (Throwable x) { x.printStackTrace(); }  because I think (possibly) you may be getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException but catching it and not printing it somewhere?